# OSX Activity monitor (energy) shows terminated terminal app with high average energy impact

Tags: macos, terminal, activity-monitor, power-management

I use my macbook like desktop (always connected to electricity) 95% of the time, so I never noticed this before. However, I had to use it on battery last few days and it surprised me how short the battery charge lasts. My macbook isn't new (about 2 years) but I would still expect it would last longer than 2 hours doing nothing but displaying static web pages.

I checked activity monitor to see where the culprit is and it shows terminated Terminal app with very high avg energy impact, even though I didn't use it in couple days. There is also Chrome app showing about quarter of the Terminal's value, but that is expected as it's the app I am actually using (and the average is higher than usual because I was watching some videos recently). After that, pretty much nothing of note. I have no idea about the values so I don't know if the values are high or not. See attached screenshot for more details:

[image]

I googled a bit about this, but I didn't find any screenshot that would show terminal app with such high impact and that got me worried. Is it possible there is something wrong with my system? I can't find any Terminal app running anywhere.

I am running El Capitan 10.11.4 on MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014)

**EDIT:**

After restart, terminal app disappeared and estimated remaining charge time almost tripled. I am not sure how to interpret this, it would seem like something started terminal app with heavy load and either kept closing it that it wouldn't show in the activity monitor or it was somehow hidden (I am OSX noob, so I have no idea if any of that is possible). I will try to see if I can determine what and why started that Terminal process

Comment: Greyed apps are no longer running, & are showing usage from earlier this session.

Comment: That's what I deduced as well, but for how long are they displayed? I didn't use terminal in quite some time

Comment: I'm not certain whether they survive logout/in or reboot. Would be simple enough to test, but I've got processes running right now I can't quit for several hours.

Comment: That's good suggestion, I will restart and see how the energy impacts look after that. Will keep you posted

Comment: It might have something to do with changes made to preserve session state starting with El Capitan, which is described at https://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/397uep/changes_to_bash_sessions_and_terminal_in_el/

Comment: I have this issue as well. While I don't know yet why it is happening I have tracked down what is causing the issue. There is a process called C-bin-86515VjP that is launched by something and is causing the energy usage to jump.